# User license enforcement: Standard CALs and personal My Site Issues

Tags: 2013, licensing, mysites

We use on-premises SharePoint 2013 in our environment, and we are experiencing a problem where all users who aren't members of the "**Enterprise CAL**" AD group are unable to get a My Site provisioned. Our Farm license is set to "`SharePoint Server with Enterprise Client Access License`" in Central Administration. We are operating with user license enforcement enabled, and there are mappings to AD groups for all of the available license types (Ent, Std, Project, WAC). We have a mixed CAL environment.

Whenever a user in the Standard CAL group tries to setup their My Site, it just goes to a basic page with "`About $username`", an option to edit the profile, a photo in the top left, and two links on the quick launch for "`About me`" and "`People`". On this page, the Newsfeed, OneDrive, and Sites links at the very top only redirect to the same page. We are trying to force the provisioning by clicking on the "`Follow`" link on any site; this produces the following message: `"Wait a minute - To follow documents or sites, we need to get a couple of things set up. This can take a few minutes to complete, and once it's done, you'll need to come back to this site and try following again.`" Clicking the "`Get Started`" button in response takes us to the previously described page; we never see the "`We're almost ready`" screen to indicate that the site is being created. The ULS log shows the the personal site instantiation fails for the affected users because these two conditions are not met:

Can Create Personal Site == False Is user licensed == False

When we change the AD membership to the Enterprise CAL group instead of the Standard CAL group, and then wait for the cached security token to expire the site does provision as expected. I know that this seems to make it obvious that it's a matter of needing to assign Enterprise CALs to the appropriate users, but after reviewing the feature/license information on Technet, it seems clear that "`Personal Sites`" are available to Standard CAL users for an on-premises farm. Please tell me if I'm wrong. On a side-note, does anyone know of a better resource that goes into clearer detail regarding licensed features for SharePoint CAL types? Here is the Technet site that we're currently referencing: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj819267.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#bkmk_FeaturesOnPremise[1]

Should Standard CAL users be able to have a My Site provisioned like we are expecting? If so, does anyone have any thoughts about where the problem could be in our environment? I really appreciate any and all feedback and comments. Thank you in advance!

Comment: looks like your license mapping is not working properly...did you follow this  https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj219627.aspx check the pwoershell at the end

Comment: what about the permission for the creation of mysite, allow creation of my sites to All Authenticated Users and NT Authority Authenticated Users should be on UPA...also try with different user with std cal